# How do I print query results in DataGrip?

Tags: printing, datagrip

Is there a way to print the results of a query in DataGrip? I can print the query (not very useful) but when I select the result pane the print option in the File menu is grayed out.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of DataGrip you are using? I have DataGrip 2016.2.1 and after selecting the result pane rows, I still have the File>Print option enabled.

Comment: Not sure why its different :( Print dialog comes for me after clicking File>Print.

Comment: I posted a screenshot

Comment: Even though Print dialog comes, it printed the query not the results. I just printed it to verify. sorry for this and I dont know how to print the result pane data :(

Comment: Yes it prints the query not the result... It's quite annoying.

Comment: May be export to csv then print the csv file is a option.

Comment: I created an issue in our tracker, please check and vote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3090

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps :

1. open view from the toolbar
2. open tool windows
3. select database changes

then you see a new tab in the console where you can monitor every changes you made (example :`select * from table`)